# Where to start repairing a faulty electronic board?

Tags: circuit-analysis, short-circuit, repair

I am working on electronic card repair of textile machines. When a faulty electronic card arrives, I visually check it first. Is there a burned or cracked componenet next to it, if any, I am replacing these parts and the fault has been fixed. Sometimes an eye-related error is not seen, the card is short-circuited and I solve it with a thermal camera. however, there are some electronic cards that do not have externally visible burns or short circuits. at this point where should my first step be to find the error of this card type? Where should I start card repair? what should i check? This type of fault usually occurs on cards that produce high voltage errors at the input or output.

In short, if there is a fault in the electronic board, where should we start repairing? Is there a order of methods?

Comment: *where should my first step be to find the error of this card type?* Dave from the EEVBlog (and many engineers with him) says: **Thou shallst measure voltages**. Watch Dave in action on his Youtube channel, here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h6D4MMWjrmM&list=PLvOlSehNtuHsc8y1buFPJZaD1kKzIxpWL Depending on the fault type and function of the board, the strategy may differ. But to get a general idea Dave's videos are a good staring point.

Comment: Check the power supply, check if all known voltages are as they should be. 90% of the errors I encounter are found that way.

Answer (score 3):

Diagnostics.

In an ideal world the card developer provides you with a step by step test sequence to identify exactly which stage is faulty. Measure these voltages, look for this waveform, inject 1 kHz 10mV here and see 1 kHz 500mV there, and so on.

If you don't have this - there is no service manual - learn the circuit well enough to develop your own. Keep one good card on hand so you know what it should do, and track the suspect card against it.

If you have a lot of similar cards, you can speed the process by making a test fixture, with connections to the test points and switches to connect them up to the test gear. Or even invest in ATE - Automated Test Equipment. (The original manufacturer almost certainly had an ATE setup programmed for this card, while it was being made)

This is all investment of course - how much time and money is worth investing in this process depends on how often you have to test it, and how valuable the working machine is...